# changing import settings in wordpress/woocommerce plugin

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi I have the current code in the plugin, when I upload the excel through this plugin with this code it generates an general image to the product(which is defined on type of product). What I would like it to do is to make a unique image to each product, which is defined in excel as a url (the file is in medialibrary of wordpress)

```
$image_id_c_1 = wtf_set_featured_image( plugins_url( '/images/C/1.jpg', __FILE__  ) );
```

How could sould the code look like to do this, would it be something like this?

```
$image_id_c_1 = wtf_set_featured_image( _url( '/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/4030.jpg', __FILE__  ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$image_id_c_1 = wtf_set_featured_image( _url( '<td>'.__('picture', 'wtf').'</td><td>'.$data[36].'</td>', __FILE__  ) );
```